# UITableView cells mixed when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

While I realise this is a popular problem among developers and there are many similar questions on Stack Overflow, none have been able to help me resolve this. There is a strange issue with a UITableView in which the individual cells are becoming mixed up, or seemingly mixed up. I believe I am reusing cells correctly and simply need a second set of eyes. Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.friendFullName.text = [users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

I am using dynamic, custom cells in a seperate UITableCell.

Comment: Better define what your issue is. What incorrect behavior, exactly, are you seeing? Your code looks right in general.

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the title, it is about UITableView.

Comment: "selected" cells are showing that they are "selected" when they aren't really.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59034/discussion-between-john-doe-and-rmaddy).

Comment: How are cells being selected? You need to reset the selected state as needed (both on and off) in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method based on the selection state kept in your data model.

Comment: cells are selected when the user taps a button, am I really suppose to somehow store a value for each cell/button?

Comment: That's up to you. It all depends on what state you need to keep track of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cell is being reused. Set your label in `willDisplayCell` instead of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   SimpleTableCell *simpleTableCell = (SimpleTableCell *)cell;
   simpleTableCell.friendFullName.text = [users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: I've tried to add `willDisplayCell` but the code I used in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` isn't working? http://tinypic.com/r/2v0j3ti/8

Comment: I have edited my response for the complete implementation. You do not call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` in `willDisplayCell`.

Comment: thanks for responding, I have updated the code. Forgive my ignorance, I am still having the issue. The bottom two cells are "highlighted" (not really) randomly and the cells still become mixed up. http://postimg.org/image/sxrq6515z/ here is a poorly drawn example: http://postimg.org/image/8dojl31kh/

Comment: Your sample code provided has nothing about buttons in it (like your drawing). So I can't debug what you haven't provided.

Comment: The buttons are defined in "SimpleTableCell.h" and "SimpleTableCell.m" which are the custom UITableCell respective files.

Comment: The buttons are everything are in a separate view obviously.